# Multiprocessing with objects?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Given the following code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "name = main"
    multiprocessing.Process(target=r.fetchFiles, args=(r.results.pop(),))

class R:
    # ...
    def fetchFiles(self, blabla):
        with open('/tmp/doyou.txt', 'w+') as f:
            f.write('do you do something?')
```

`r` is an instance of `R`. The test file does not get written. Why?

Comment: Why is r an instance of R? Your code does not show that. For multiprocessing to work, put all your code in functions.

Comment: Appreciate that I didn't paste 18000 lines of code. Thanks.

Comment: Please give a minimal example that should work, nonetheless.

Comment: Why don't call `r.results.pop()` on locally ?

Comment: I will try that, thanks.

Comment: Why multiprocessing at all if you write everything into one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process needs to be [started](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class):

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=r.fetchFiles, args=(r.results.pop(),))
process.start()
process.join()
```

A simple working example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class R:
    def print_value(self, value):
        print(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = Process(target=R().print_value, args=('a',))
    process.start()
    process.join()
```